# Blocking writes to a console in C++ Qt Qt5.0

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How do I block until a line has finished executing?

My code reads from two serial ports and writes the output of both to a single console. The idea is to write all the output from the first serial port, then all the output from the second serial port. How do I block the second write to the console until the first one has finished writing to the console?

Sleep does not work. All it does is write the first character of the first putData, wait 1 second, and dump the rest of the first serial port mixed up with the second serial port output.

Here is the relevant method:

```
void MainWindow::readData() 
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
    console->putData(data);

    Sleep(1000); //This does not work.

    QByteArray data2 = serial2->readAll();
    console->putData(data2);
}
```

[Win 7, Qt 5.0, Qt Creator].

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why readAll() is giving you single characters instead of the entire message but you could try something like that:

```
void MainWindow::readData() 
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
    console->putData(data);

    if(data.isEmpty())
    {
        QByteArray data2 = serial2->readAll();
        console->putData(data2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the signals not being correct. They were not correctly writing to the console's slot.